# Install SQL Server 2008 client on windows 8

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How do I install SQL Server 2008 client on Windows 8? It gives me compatibility issue. Can SQL Server Native Client 11.0 work for accessing SQL Server 2008 R2 remotely?

> Solve a problem with Microsoft SQL Server (2008 and 2008 R2)
>
> Your version of Microsoft SQL Server (2008 and 2008 R2) isn't compatible with this version of Windows.

Can I access SQL Server 2008 R2 using client of SQL Server 2012/2014?

Comment: can you post the exact error?

Comment: I have changed the description.

Comment: I have sql server 2008 R2 installed on my machine which has windows 8.1 and it works fine.

Comment: Have you check to see if you have a 32 or 64 bit machine and matching installation media?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it installed using Web Platform Installer. 
You can download it here http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access a SQL 2008 r2 server from the latter versions. I currently do this at work. As to why 2008 isn't working on windows 8 verify you have 2008 r2 install and not just 2008.